# Rails and SQL - Joining by multiple table columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm still trying to learn SQL and I could use some help ordering by different attributes. What I'm trying to do is get all `products` and `skus` and order them first by the `collection.name`, then by the `sku.name`. However, both the collection name and the sku name are in different tables that are associated with the products table by a foreign key.

So it would look something like this

```
product.id | collection.name | product.name | sku.name
1          | Apple           | Lateral File | A34
3          | Beaumont        | Desk         | BT450
2          | Beaumont        | Hutch        | BT451
5          | Beaumont        | Drawer       | BT452
7          | Vista           | File         | V246
6          | Waterfall       | TV Stand     | WF899
```

Any help is appreciated

Here are my models:

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible               :name, 
                                :title,
                                :features,
                                :collection_id,
                                :skus_attributes


  belongs_to                    :collection

  has_many                      :skus, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skus, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:title].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible   :name, 
                    :title,
                    :description

  has_many :products
end
```

**sku.rb**

```
class Sku < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('skus.id ASC')

  attr_accessible               :name,
                                :title,
                                :product_id

  belongs_to                    :product

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a result similar to the one you posted above, you could try something like:

```
Product.joins(:collection, :skus)
       .select('products.id, collections.name, products.name, skus.name')
       .order('collections.name ASC, skus.name ASC')
```

Comment: And what will this return?

Answer (score 0):

You not gonna get that exact result in Rails, because that's not what Rails is for. However if you want to get all products ordered by collection name and sku name, that's the way

```
Product.joins(:collection, :skus).order('collections.name, skis.name')
```

but since in your model Product can have many SKUs I'm not completely sure about the result of that query.

Comment: What if I just skip the skus.name and just order by collections.name?